# Printing with unicode right to left override not working as expected

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to print something right to left in Python using the `u202E` unicode RLO and it's not working.  I've tried this in iTerm2 and Terminal on MacOS 12.4 and 11.6.7 using Python 3.9.1, 3.8.2, and 2.7.5.

```
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
```

When I try to print right to left using this format:
`print (u"\u202EBlah")`

Which prints:
`Blah`

I expect the output to be:

> halB

What am I doing wrong?  iTerm is set for `utf-8` as well.

Comment: That prints the way around that you expect for me Python 3.8, macOS

Comment: I'm sure it depends on the capabilities of your console.

Comment: Tried answer below and got the same results as posted on multiple terminals on a couple of different MacOS versions and different versions of Python.  I also tried it as a script and in the python interface.  I think this might be an OS issue and not a coding issue.  I may close this and open it in a different community.

Answer (score -2):

Running the following code on Google Colab and Pycharm results in the correct output given in the answer:

```
import sys
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
print(u"\u202EBlah")
```

> > utf-8
> > ‮Blah

Make sure your Python version is `3.x`, it may be a version error, as it works well on Windows 10 and Linux.

Comment: It's IDE-specific.  It doesn't work correctly from the Windows command prompt, at least not on US Windows.  It *might* work on a RTL language-localized Windows.  It works correctly in the PyWin32 PythonWin IDE.